# none, none, Newland, Portage, Plano

Tags: knowledge, sequence

What is the pattern behind this list of US cities? Really quite simple for US folk, and I think most educated foreigners have the requisite background info.

| US City | US State |
| --- | --- |
| Añasco | PR |
| Carolina | PR |
| none |  |
| Nantucket | MA |
| none |  |
| none |  |
| none |  |
| none |  |
| Newland | NC |
| Portage | IN |
| Plano | TX |

A friend of mine made the following image, which is pretty but not necessarily helpful!
[image: map of Eastern USA]
([Table as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l20c4.png))

Comment: This is diabolical! I've come up with what I thought were 2 good leads, but they haven't taken me anywhere: 1: it looks like rot13(n Svobanppv frdhrapr jurer gurer vf ab erfhyg sbe bar, ohg gjb, guerr naq svir fbzrubj rdhngr gb Arjynaq, Cbegntr naq Cynab). and 2:  rot13(gur bayl fgngr jvgu nyy guerr pvgvrf vf Vaqvnan)

Comment: All I is that the states are progressing westward on the map and the places within them are progressing alphabetically

Comment: The west to east property is a consequence of the underlying pattern, I think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This puzzle combines two things:

> **[ZIP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code)** (postal codes used in the U.S.) and **[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence)**.

The title: none, none, Newland, Portage, Plano

> ZIP codes use a five-digit format. There are five Fibonacci numbers with five digits: **10946**, **17711**, **28657**, **46368** and **75025**. The first two numbers are not valid ZIP codes (or at least not valid ZIP codes assigned to locations), but the next three numbers are the ZIP code of **[Newland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newland,_North_Carolina)**, North Carolina; the ZIP code of **[Portage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portage,_Indiana)**, Indiana and one of the ZIP codes assigned to **[Plano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano,_Texas)**, Texas.

The table: Añasco, Carolina, Nantucket

> ZIP codes may have leading zeros, which yields three more numbers that are both Fibonacci numbers and valid ZIP codes: **00610** for **[Añasco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1asco,_Puerto_Rico)**, Puerto Rico; **00987** for parts of **[Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolina,_Puerto_Rico)**, Puerto Rico and **02584** for parts of **[Nantucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantucket)**, Massachusetts.

Comment: Perfect! This captures it all! The title, with the duplicate first term was intended to “suggest” Fibonacci